# Unobtrusive validation: how to run javascript before validating a textbox content as a number?

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I have a textbox that is being populated by a scanner, which inserts extra spaces, newline, tabs, etc. I need to clean those before firing the validation. My code:

```
[Integer(ErrorMessage = "Survey ID must be a number.")]
public long? SurveyRecipientID { get; set; }

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SurveyRecipientID)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SurveyRecipientID, "Survey ID")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SurveyRecipientID)
```